# VSCode Dart & Flutter unusably slow on MacOS

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Flutter & Dart becomes unbearably slow in VSCode all of a sudden. Intellisense won't load within 30+ seconds, syntax highlighting won't update, etc.

I tried uninstalling all extensions, even completely removing VSCode with any data stored and reinstalling it. As soon as I install the Dart extension, it is unusable. I also tried setting the following settings:

```
"dart.previewLsp": true,
"dart.useLegacyAnalyzerProtocol": true,
"dart.useLsp": false,
"dart.autoImportCompletions": false,
```

I'm on macOS 14.4, VSCode Version 1.87.2 (Universal)

In the Activity Monitor, there is the `dart:analysis_server.dart.snapshot` process running with around 1 GB of used memory. I'm not sure if this is normal.